# Initializing default ignored vendors/app.php after checkout/clone

Tags: composer-php, cakephp-3.0

The .gitignore is configured to ignore /vendor/*.

When I checkout the code on another machine, the vendors are missing. How do I initialize them into this other machine?

How about the default initialization of app.php (SALT for instance)?

Comment: By executing `composer install`?

Comment: Apparently, that did the trick! Feel free to add this as an answer and I'll acccept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per @ndm's comment, simply run the following in your working copy:

```
composer install
```